# Telegram bug on iOS bot sending multiple times same message

Tags: ios, telegram, telegram-bot

I think I've found a Telegram bug on the iOS app that causes the bot to send multiple times the same message. The steps to reproduce the problem are:

- click on an inline button, type callback
- immediately lock the phone screen, before the bot answers
- wait a few moments and then unlock the screen

It will be noticed at this point that the bot starts sending the same message numerous times. It is not easy to reproduce, it is important to lock the screen when the bot has not yet answered, so it is easier with bots that take a few moments to respond. Also, in the answer the bot has to send a message (not editing one that already exist).

I use Microsoft Bot Framework to develop the bot, however all the bots give me the same problem, both mine and others developed with other technologies different from mine. For example, I was able to reproduce it on @BotFather too. Sometimes it enters in a loop, and to stop it you have to send any message to the bot.
I use an iPhone 5, iOS version 12.1.2, Telegram version 5.2. I also tried it on an iPhone 8, but not with other versions of Telegram.
I also happen to receive more than 20 identical messages.

---

I've already contacted Bot Support on Telegram but no one answers me. Is there anyone who experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS and macOS,  when  I click on an inline button  and switch the client computer (macbook) off (sleep mode) and turn it on my bot receives the last message sent by the user. Each time message_id is the same.
I solve it the following way: when my script sends a request to the Telegram server it receives a response. That response contains a message_id field and I save it.

Any next message must have another message_id. I just compare that number with the stored number and only if the number is other than saved I run the rest part of my script.

You can try my test bot and watch results in google table.

@ios_bug_bot (https://t.me/ios_bug_bot)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VTx-O1w_-ka1RzGfaVLVBDu0CQxk16QeJTeFYOE4yvo/edit?usp=sharing

The bot source code is here

https://github.com/avtomatron/telegram_bot/blob/master/google_script_bot

Comment: Hi, I'm glad someone else ran into this problem, it's a proof that this is actually a telegram bug.

We found that Bot Framework doesn't send AnswerCallbackQuery (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) after sending a message to the user and the bug only occurs if the user exits the telegram client (blocking the device or 'iconizing' the app) before the bot is able to send the AnswerCallbackQuery.

This is why we send it our own immediatly as soon as the user's message arrives (even before answering with the bot).

Comment: This reduces the possibility of the bug occurring but does not cancel it altogether, so as you did we also keep the message ID aside and if following messages from the user have the same ID we do not respond.

In this way though if the user clicks the button again, the message ID is the same and we cannot know if it was the user pressing again the button or if it was the bug. This way the bot will never respond.

Comment: The only thing that came to our mind is this: together with the message ID we also set aside the timestamp of the message and when a message with the same ID arrives we check if at least 5 seconds have passed from the timestamp we set aside. If so, AnswerCallbackQuery was almost certainly already sent and so it was probably the user that clicked the button and we let the bot respond, otherwise we block the answer of the bot.

Comment: Sombe, I changed my answer, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, but it is not a telegram bug. When dealing with callback buttons, you must use **answerCallbackQuery**. Otherwise telegram thinks the callback was not handled and repeats the messages.

I use .net and the telegram.bot library and that fixes the problem.

```
 await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(request.CallbackQueryId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```